# Construct the state diagram for TM

Tags: turing-machines

Consider the language  = {a<sup>3<sup>n</sup></sup>; n>=0}.

Construct the state diagram for TM.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem, and where specifically are you stuck with your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Any string a^(3^n) for n >= 0 has a number of a which is either one or evenly divisible by three. We can exploit this as follows:

1. cross off 2 instances of a on the end of the string for every 1 instance of a on the front
2. repeat until there is only a single a remaining, then halt accept
3. if at any point you can't follow rules 1 and 2, halt reject

An implementation of this idea is the following

```
Q    T    Q'    T'    D        comment

q0   a    q1    A     right    ensure at least one a
q1   a    q2    a     right    if multiple a, keep going
q1   #    h_a   #     left     if one a, halt accept

q2   a    q2    a     right    scan all the way to the end 
q2   #    q3    #     left     go to last a     
q3   a    q4    #     left     erase it, go to new last a
q4   a    q5    #     left     erase it, go to new last a

q5   a    q5    a     left     scan back to the first marked a
q5   A    q6    A     right

q6   a    q2    A     right    have another a, start scanning again
q6   #    q7    #     left     no more a, reset tape

q7   A    q7    a     left     scan to beginning, unmarking all a
q7   #    q0    #     right    start process over from the beginning
```

This TM works by iterative transforming the input tape a^(3^n) into a^(3^(n-1)) until it is either a^1 or it doesn't evenly divide at some stage.

Example:

```
001            002            003            004
#aaaaaaaaa#    #Aaaaaaaaa#    #Aaaaaaaaa#    #Aaaaaaaaa#
 ^               ^               ^               ^
 q0              q1              q2              q2


005            006            007             008
#Aaaaaaaaa#    #Aaaaaaaaa#    #Aaaaaaaaa#     #Aaaaaaaaa#
     ^               ^               ^                ^
     q2              q2              q2               q2


009            010            011             012
#Aaaaaaaaa#    #Aaaaaaaaa#    #Aaaaaaaaa#     #Aaaaaaaa##
         ^               ^             ^              ^
         q2              q2            q3             q4


 013           014            015            016
#Aaaaaaa###    #Aaaaaaa###    #Aaaaaaa###    #Aaaaaaa###
       ^             ^             ^             ^
       q5            q5            q5            q5


017            018            019            020
#Aaaaaaa###    #Aaaaaaa###    #Aaaaaaa###    #Aaaaaaa###
   ^             ^             ^               ^
   q5            q5            q5              q6


021            022            023            024
#AAaaaaa###    #AAaaaaa###    #AAaaaaa###    #AAaaaaa###
   ^               ^               ^               ^
   q2              q2              q2              q2


025            026            027            028
#AAaaaaa###    #AAaaaaa###    #AAaaaaa###    #AAaaaa####
       ^               ^             ^             ^
       q2              q2            q3            q4


029            030            031            032
#AAaaaa####    #AAaaaa####    #AAaaaa####    #AAaaa#####
     ^             ^             ^             ^
     q5            q5            q5            q5


033            034            035            036
#AAaaa#####    #AAAaa#####    #AAAaa#####    #AAAaa#####
   ^               ^               ^               ^
   q6              q2              q2              q2


037            038            039            040
#AAaaa#####    #AAAa######    #AAA#######    #AAA#######
     ^             ^             ^               ^
   q3              q4            q5              q6


041            042            043            044
#AAA#######    #AAa#######    #Aaa#######    #aaa#######
   ^             ^             ^             ^
   q7            q7            q7            q7


045            046            047            048
#aaa#######    #Aaa#######    #Aaa#######    #Aaa#######
 ^               ^               ^               ^
 q0              q1              q2              q2


049            050            051            052
#Aaa#######    #Aa########    #A#########    #A#########
   ^             ^             ^               ^
   q3            q4            q5              q6


053            054            055            056
#A#########    #a#########    #a#########    #a#########
 ^             ^               ^               ^
 q7            q7              q0              q1


049
#a#########
 ^
 h_a
```